# How to tell if datagridview column is an image or checkbox column?

Tags: c#, types, datagridview, detection

I'm trying to create a custom function that saves the content of a datagridview to a file. I'm doing this instead of serializing because my custom function is designed to be as easy and quick to implement as possible to save and load the winform's state, and creating custom classes every time I want to serialize an object is not as easy and quick as possible.

To do this, I need to programmatically detect which columns in a datagridview are either image columns or checkbox columns so I know how to handle them appropriately when loading. I looked online and it appears that there is no one else who's mentioned it yet (as far as my Google searches would've suggested), but I'm absolutely sure that there is some way to tell what kind of cell/column some cell/column is. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this -

```
        foreach (var col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            if (col is DataGridViewImageColumn)
            {
                // Image Column
            }

            if (col is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
            {
                // CheckBox Column
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just compare to type:

```
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (col.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn))
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if (col.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewImageColumn))
            {
                // do something else
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you validate? This won't compile in C#

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells) {
    if (dc.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewImageCell)) {

    }
  }
}
```

This should work... including the cells!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 For each col in datagridview.columns   
   If col.CellType.Name = "DataGridViewImageColumn" Then
   'do something
   End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into

```
column.ValueType
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is what I'm using:

```
Dim colType As Type = DataGridView1.Columns(0).GetType
If colType.Name = "DataGridViewImageColumn" Then
'code for image column type
End If
```

Credits:
[Link to VB forums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559644-Counting-Particular-Letter-Occurrences-in-a-String)